# Show the number of incompleted/invalid form fields/elements

Tags: angular, validation, angular-forms

I need to show the number of incompleted/invalid form fields that are remaining on a form as it is being completed.

Can't seem to find anything out there for this and i'm not sure where to begin.

How would I go about doing this?

I currently have a reactive form with validation.

Any help would be great.

HTML

```
 <form [formGroup]="quote" (ngSubmit)="post(quote.value)">

 <!-- TITLE -->
<fieldset class="help-hover">
<div class="question-wrapper">
  <label class="question" for="quoteFormTitle">Your title</label>
  <div class="answer">
    <select formControlName="quoteFormTitle" id="quoteFormTitle" class="chosen-select">
      <option value="" disabled>Choose a title...</option>
      <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
      <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
      <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
      <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
      <option value="Doctor Male">Doctor - Male</option>
      <option value="Doctor Female">Doctor - Female</option>
    </select>
    <span class="tick-area"></span>
    <div class="error" *ngIf="quoteFormTitle.touched && quoteFormTitle.invalid">Please select a title.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<aside class="help">
  <p>Please select your title from the drop down list.</p>
</aside>
</fieldset>

<!-- FIRSTNAME -->
<fieldset class="help-hover">
<div class="question-wrapper">
  <label class="question" for="quoteFormFirstName">First name</label>
  <div class="answer">
    <input formControlName="quoteFormFirstName" id="quoteFormFirstName" class="textbox" type="text" />
    <span class="tick-area"></span>
    <div class="error" *ngIf="quoteFormFirstName.touched && quoteFormFirstName.invalid">
      <div *ngIf="quoteFormFirstName.errors.required">Your first name is required.</div>
      <div *ngIf="quoteFormFirstName.errors.minlength">Your first name must be more than {{ quoteFormFirstName.errors.minlength.requiredLength }} characters.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<aside class="help">
  <p>Don’t worry, your personal information is important to us and we’ll never sell your details on to other companies.
    We will only pass them on to our business partners for the purposes of fulfilling your quote.</p>
</aside>
</fieldset>

<!-- SURNAME -->
<fieldset class="help-hover">
<div class="question-wrapper">
  <label class="question" for="quoteFormSurname">Surname</label>
  <div class="answer">
    <input formControlName="quoteFormSurname" id="quoteFormSurname" class="textbox" type="text" />
    <span class="tick-area"></span>
    <div class="error" *ngIf="quoteFormSurname.touched && quoteFormSurname.invalid">
      <div *ngIf="quoteFormSurname.errors.required">Your surname is required.</div>
      <div *ngIf="quoteFormSurname.errors.minlength">Your surname must be more than {{ quoteFormSurname.errors.minlength.requiredLength }} characters.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<aside class="help">
  <p>Don’t worry, your personal information is important to us and we’ll never sell your details on to other companies.
    We will only pass them on to our business partners for the purposes of fulfilling your quote.</p>
</aside>
</fieldset>

<button class="button-primary float-right"
 [disabled]="!quote.valid">Submit</button>

 <p>You have {{ x }} amount of questions remaining</p>

 </form>
```

Comment: Add your code here that you've tried already, Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but a problem-solving one.

Comment: There are too many ways to solve this depending on what you have and what you need. You could set a variable that increments when your validation functions fail, you could do checks on your inputs before sending the data etc...

Comment: I just need to show the number of incomplete/invalid fields left in the form on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that all your fields have some sort of validation, which means that we can in the beginning count all fields and set the initial value of the invalid fields as amount of properties you have.

What you can do, is to subscribe to `valueChanges` of the form, iterate the properties (form controls) and check if there is something in the `errors` property of the form controls. If there is, it will have an object with the errors, if not, `errors` will be `null`. We can then in the iteration increment the property you are using for displaying the number of invalid fields. So this works with a single form group with form controls (which you seem to have). Here's a sample for you, just apply it to your code:

```ts
myForm: FormGroup;

numOfNotValidFields: number; // property to count invalid fields

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    first_name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
    last_name: ['', [Validators.required]]
  });

  // get amount of properties initially, meaning all are invalid
  this.numOfNotValidFields = Object.keys(this.myForm.controls).length;

  this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
    // (re)initialize variable
    this.numOfNotValidFields = 0;
    // iterate the form object properties
    for(let prop in this.myForm.controls) {
      if(this.myForm.controls[prop].errors) {
        this.numOfNotValidFields++;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**[Here's DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ycfwu2?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks Alex, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Much appreciated.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it fit your requirements! Have a nice weekend and happy coding!! :) :)